# Qt MVC insert new column and setItemDelegateForColumn

Tags: qt, model-view-controller

I use `setItemDelegateForColumn` to set delegate for each column in the view, but after inserting a new column in the view (not insert at the end), the index of each column will change, so the delegate will be no longer set for the same column as it used to be.
How to set delegate for column but not based on the column index, because the column index will always change after inserting new column ?

Comment: You should create complex delegate, that wraps your delegates and calls necessary methods, depends on column role.